# Python -- suppress console output for a constantly running thread, not the entire program

Tags: python, multithreading, console

BLUF: Is there a way to suppress console output just for a single thread?

I have a background thread that does system checks which include a bunch of pings to various things.  These ping checks take awhile and then the results are flushed to the console.  I don't want them to display at all, so I found that you can set stdout to devnull.

The problem there is that the system checks are in a while True loop (with a 60 second sleep between loops) and the checks themselves take up a good portion of that 60 seconds so I'm afraid suppressing console output during these functions will result in no console output for a good percentage of total runtime for the entire program -- console output I might later want to see from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace sys.stdout with a custom class that filters output based on thread.